# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import math

def calculate(x):
    while x**2+math.sqrt(x) < 4:
      x = x+0.000001
    print(x)

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("300x150")

button = Button(gui, text="Udregn", command=calculate).pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

I try to use this code and hit the button to make it calculate, however it gives me this error once I press the button instead:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: udregn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Comment: What do you expect the value of `x` to be?

Answer (score 3):

`Button` callbacks are not called with any arguments, which makes sense, because the only information a button provides is that it has been clicked. You'll have to define the function like this:

```
def calculate():
    ...
```

and think about another approach for how to get a value of `x` for inside the function. Typically, it will come from another GUI component, which you can either access as a global value, or you can have `calculate` be a bound method of an object that encapsulates `x`.

```
class XContainer(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def calculate(self):
        while self.x**2+math.sqrt(self.x) < 4:
            self.x += 0.000001
        print(self.x)


x = XContainer(5)
button = Button(gui, text="Udregn", command=x.calculate)
button.pack()
```

In this case, some other code will be responsible for creating and possibly modifying `x`.

Comment: So it's impossible for me to use a while loop in this kind of function?

Comment: You can use a loop; you just can't have any arguments to the function. See my update.

Comment: With your code I get this error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Mathias/Documents/Projects/Skole Python 3/test2.py", line 13, in calculate
    while x**2+math.sqrt(x) < 4:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Comment: Be careful doing things like `button = Button(...).pack()`.  In this case, `button` will be `None` since `tkinter.Widget.pack` returns `None`.

Comment: @mgilson I don't seem to understand, could you maybe clarify a bit?

Comment: @WincyGaming -- I'm not sure what's unclear.  Try printing `button` (after you define it) and you'll see that it's value is `None`.  Generally you want to create the button and then put it on the grid in 2 separate steps rather than 1 chained step e.g.:  `button = Button(...); button.pack()`

Comment: @mgilson That made no difference what so ever. :/

Comment: @WincyGaming -- I didn't claim that it would fix whatever problem you were having.  If it would fix the problem you are having, I would have posted it as an answer :-).  I'm just trying to warn you of another pitfall that I have seen many times that can break your code in other ways.

Comment: I've made the change in my answer, as it is necessary if you actually need a reference to the button elsewhere in the code; otherwise, you can just use `Button(...).pack()`.

Comment: @chepner - don't forget that you can also use a lambda, so you can do a command=lambda: calculate(x) to pass a variable.  Still have to have x defined somewhere the function can see it, but this enhances your options.